# PostgreSQL - define query result's timezone

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have a query where the clause is based on any data uploaded after a certain date:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table_data da
WHERE da.uploaded_at > '2023-06-27 14:59:22.947058 +00:00'::TIMESTAMP
```

When I execute it thought Intellij IDEA using [Database Tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2023.1/database-tool-window.html) plugin it returns:

| ID | UPLOADED_AT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-06-29 19:49:18.103044+00 |

But, when I execute it though a Java class using a JDBC connection, it returns:

| ID | UPLOADED_AT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-06-29 21:49:18.103044+02 |

Where this returned timezone is defined?

Environment:

- PostgreSQL 11.9 (UTF)
- Java 8

```java
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
     PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql))
{
     ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

     while (resultSet.next())
     {
          System.out.println(resultSet.getString("id") + "|" + resultSet.getString("uploaded_at")));
     }

}
(...)
```

Comment: Presumably, the default time zone of your system is at UTC+2 (e.g. Europe/Berlin)?

Comment: What's the data type of `uploaded_at` in your database? Also, both results represent the same _instant_ in time, only the representations differ. And why don't you read it from the DB as `java.sql.Timestamp` instead of a `String` and then convert it to `java.time.Instant` and from there apply whatever time zone to get the representation you need?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yes, my time zone is UTC+2, and I executing both Intellij Database tool and Java app from the same machine.

Comment: @MarkusRatzer uploaded_at is a TIMESTAMP. It's exactly the representation I want to understand why it differs from one to other.

Comment: I usually prefer `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` as data type instead of `TIMESTAMP`. Don't be confused though, in the DB there's still no timezone information stored (so, only UTC), but the behaviour is different when reading/writing from/to the DB.

Comment: The problem is that you're casting to `TIMESTAMP`, not `TIMESTAMPTZ`.

Comment: Another thing you can investigate: `resultSet.getObject("updated_at", Instant.class)` can be used to get the, well, instant stored in the DB. You then can use `Instant`'s methods `atOffset(...)` or `atZone(...)` (and then _maybe_ `toLocalDateTime()`) to get the desired representation.

Comment: And to answer your actual question: as @MarkRotteveel indicated, some automatic conversion happens _somewhere_ depending on your local time zone settings. This is either done by the JDBC driver on the client side (_may_ be configurable) or by the DB itself on the server side (_may_ be configurable, e.g. via the connection string or some statement in the beginning of a new DB session).

Comment: @MarkusRatzer Be aware that support for `Instant` is not defined by the JDBC specification, I believe the PostgreSQL JDBC driver supports it, but it is non-standard. `LocalDateTime` is defined for (JDBC type) `TIMESTAMP`, and `OffsetDateTime` for (JDBC type) `TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the different behavior was caused by the JDBC connector using the client's time zone (UTC+2) and for some reason neither [Database Tools](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2023.1/database-tool-window.html) nor PGAdmin I executed the query use the client's time zone. They either set it as UTC (matching my database configuration) or somehow use the database time zone.

In order to have the same behavior I managed to set the time zone on my Java class execution passing a VM option

```
 -Duser.timezone=UTC
```